# Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-firebase

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I have a React Native version `0.60.4` app where i have installed `react-native-firebase` version `"^5.2.3"`. Now when i give the `react-native run-android` it shows the following error:

[image]

I can not link react-native-firebase as it is not supported in react-native 0.60.4. I have tried running  `cd android && gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android` but no luck. Here's my android/app/build.gradle :

```js
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: false,
]
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility '1.8'
        targetCompatibility '1.8'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.movitpilot"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        // minifyEnabled true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libjsc.so'
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  
    

    if (enableHermes) {
      def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermesvm/android/";
      debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
      releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
      implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Notice if your problem was resolved!

Comment: No it's not. The settings.gradle file contains just this: rootProject.name = 'myproject'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'

Comment: That should not bring that error like what you shared! Check PackageList.java please.

Comment: Here's the PackageList.java : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3fk4bo?embed=1&file=index.js.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `implementation project(':react-native-firebase')` from `build.gralde` file. According to new Auto-linking process there is no need to implement project in `app/build.gradle`.
And also make sure no modules linked in `settings.gradle` like this:

```
rootProject.name = 'MyApp'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
```

If there is any try to unlink module through `react-native unlink react-native-firebase` **if you are using react-native >= 0.60**

Comment: Tried that. Still the same. @MatinZD

Comment: @TanmoySarker How is that possible ! The same error !?

Comment: Yes, still same.

Comment: Please share your `build.gradle` file again or update your post as I said.

Comment: Try unlinking your module. `react-native unlink react-native-firebase` then `react-native run-android`

Comment: Please share your settings.gradle too! Module might have been added through manual linking. Post updated :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is install again

```
npm i react-native-firebase@5.2.3
```

You need to check `react-native-firebase` exist or not in folder `node_modules`

Answer (score 0):

this may happen when you deleted the package from the **node-modules** folder or you made a wrong declaration of react-native-firebase in **package.json**.
to resolve this problem :

1. delete **react-native-firebase** from ***package.json*** file.
2. delete the **react-native-firebase** package from *node-modules*(if you want to keep your node modules packages clear ).
3. reinstall your dependency again:

> `npm I react-native-firebase`

.

make sure you have no duplicated packages with the same rule in your node-module folder .